# Get text in same list item as button

Tags: javascript, list

is it possible to get the text of a list item with the press of a button that is inside the list? I cant identify it by id because it would change based on what the user inputs.

**HTML looks like this:**

```
    <ul>
<li>remove this<button>X</button></li>
<li>or this<button>X</button></li>
</ul>
```

**What I got so far in Javascript:**

1. This only gets the "X" of the button, because that is the "this.innerHTML" so it obviously dos not work:

   ```
   function getListElement(){
       let getThis = this.innerHTML;
       alert(getThis);
   }
   ```

Note that if using innerHTML on the list item, this would return: `"remove this<button>X</button>"`. I need to get the text before the button tags.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle `click` event and read `wholeText` of the `previousSibling`:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>remove this
        <button id="btn_1">X</button>
    </li>
    <li>or this
        <button id="btn_2">X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function applyBindings() {
    document.getElementById("btn_1").addEventListener("click", respond);
    document.getElementById("btn_2").addEventListener("click", respond);
}

applyBindings();


function respond(event) {
    alert(event.target.previousSibling.wholeText);
}
```

Comment: PreviousSiblin was just what I was looking for! For my code I had to use: this.previousSibling.wholeText. Thanks for the help